# Adicionar dias a um jDateChooser

Tags: java

Gostaria de adicionar 45 dias na minha data2, a partir da data1 Exemplo:

data2 = data1+45

```
 public void adiciona(Usuario usuario){


    String sql = "INSERT INTO usuario(nome,endereco,cpf,email,telefone,data1,data2) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {

       PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
       java.sql.Date data1 = new java.sql.Date(usuario.getData1().getTime()); 


       stmt.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
       stmt.setString(2, usuario.getEndereco());
       stmt.setString(3, usuario.getCpf());           
       stmt.setString(4, usuario.getEmail());
       stmt.setString(5, usuario.getTelefone());
       stmt.setDate(6, data1);
       stmt.setDate(7, data2 );  //QUERO ADICIONAR A DATA2 NO BANCO COM 45 DIAS APÓS A DATA1, COMO FAZER?

       stmt.execute();
       stmt.close();

    } catch (SQLException u) {
        throw new RuntimeException(u);
    }
}
```

interface

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
// instanciando a classe Usuario do pacote modelo e criando seu objeto usuarios
Usuario usuarios = new Usuario();
usuarios.setNome(jTextField1.getText()); 
usuarios.setEndereco(jTextField2.getText());
usuarios.setCpf(jTextField3.getText());
usuarios.setEmail(jTextField4.getText());
usuarios.setTelefone(jTextField5.getText());
usuarios.setData1(jDateChooser1.getDate());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tiver que usar as bibliotecas nativas pré Java 8 pode fazer assim:

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); //pega data e hora atual
java.sql.Date data1 = new java.sql.Date(c1.getTimeInMillis()); //transforma p/ java.sql.Date
System.out.println(data1); //imprime para testar
c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 45); //soma 45 dias
data1.setTime(c1.getTimeInMillis()); //transforma para java.sql.Date
System.out.println(data1);//imprime para testar
```

Resultado:

> 2014-08-07
>   2014-09-21

O código acima é apenas um exemplo funcional, para seu caso você precisará associar à váriavel `c1` o valor da sua variável `data1`, assim:

```
c1.setTime(data1);
```

ao invés de pegar data e hora atuais. Ao mesmo tempo, perceba que onde eu criei `data1` no meu exemplo eu fiz justamente o caminho inverso, inicializei ele com o valor de `c1`. Ambos os casos são possíveis.

Comment: Parceiro, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Resolvi meu problema. Agora seguinte.. Meu sistema precisa enviar e-mails 2 dias antes de cada data. Como me aconselha a fazer isso? Seria o caso de toda vez que o sistema ligar ele verificar se há e-mails para ser enviado? se puder dar uma luz, seria otimo!! Obrigado dnv pela ajuda!

Comment: @user11464 apesar de essa ser uma questão completamente nova e você poder criar um novo tópico para ela, vou dizer o que acho aqui pois não vou me alongar muito. Depende um pouco como seu sistema funciona, se você liga o sistema todo dia você pode verificar sim do jeito que você falou, se ele fica ligado o tempo inteiro deverá incluir algum timer ou definir algum evento que acionará a verificação da necessidade do envio do email. Se meu comentário te deixou com dúvidas crie uma nova pergunta, e não se esqueça de dar bastante detalhes, inclusive falando se é um sistema web, desktop ou Android.

Answer (score 0):

Quando precisei usei esta função e funcionou muito bem:

```
   public Date somaDias(Date data, int dias) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

        cal.setTime(data);

        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dias);

        return cal.getTime();
    }
```